# Laravel wild card problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, wildcard

I have `master.blade.php` as one of my layouts. When I load `post.blade.php` in browser without a wildcard like `url:localhost8000/post`  it works and full required page is loaded but when I use a wild card `url:localhost8000/post/1` the page is not completely loaded. Only the footer is displayed. Header and body appears white fire bug shows the data is present which is passed through the wildcard.

Both the pages should appear as same because the difference is only of wildcard in url.

My route file is

```
Route::get('post','PostsController@index');
Route::get('post/{post}','PostsController@show');
```

Here is my PostsController

```
class PostsController extends Controller{
public function index(){
    return view('posts.post');
}

public function show(Post $post){
    return view('posts.post',compact('post'));
}
}
```

Comment: What is the content of **posts.blade.php**?

Comment: \@extends('layouts.master')

\@section('pageHeader')
    {{ $post->heading }}
\@stop

\@section('pageHeaderDescription')
    {{$post->subheading}}
\@stop

\@section('bodyContent')
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            </div>
        </div>
\@stop

Comment: sorry for rough text. i dont know how to make it the code looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this kind of error happens, there is most likely a PHP variable error in your project.

A way to find out is to view source of the HTML and look at the first or last part of the page depending on where the error is occurring.

Also, I assume you have properly bound the keyword 'id' in your routes, in your `Post` model.

Comment: it only occurs when a wild card is added to url. I have checked the code many times. I am unable to find the error.

Comment: Did you look at the html source generated by blade? If you paste a link to your posts.blade.php and your html you may be able to get a better feedback.

Comment: how can i make a link?

Comment: i found it. it is the error with my <link href="/css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> file. maybe i dont know how to use js nodes or something. the command prompt says ''''Unexpected EOF''

Answer (score 0):

You should pass id instead of object because your url is passing an integer `localhost:8000/post/1`

```
class PostsController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        return view('posts.post');
    }

    public function show($id){
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.post',compact('post'));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is also not working. I think it is some thing to do with my master.blade.php file???

Comment: yes probably, try edit your post and adding the blade file

Comment: why there is a \@stop ? it should be \@endsection right ? @Ahmed Khan

Comment: @stop is fine. i have confirmed it from laracasts

Comment: i found it. it is the error with my <link href="/css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> file. maybe i dont know how to use js nodes or something. the command prompt says ''''Unexpected EOF'''

Answer (score 0):

if u include some assets files like CSS or JS files to the HTML document the file path should start with a forward slash for example instead of 'assets/css/foo.css' you should write '/assets/css/foo.css' it worked for me when all the document was loading but the footer didn`t